# Expand Windows Environment variable with boost or standard library

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, std

I want to replace this function with modern C++ coding maybe using boost or standard library from c++ 17, is it possible to make this without calling twice the ExpandEnvironmentStrings or at least to get rid of the malloc ?

```
void ReplaceEnviromentVariables(CString& str)
{
    DWORD dwSize;
    TCHAR *pBuff;

    // Get buffer size
    dwSize = ::ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str, NULL, 0);
    if (dwSize == 0)
        return; // error

    pBuff = (TCHAR*)malloc(dwSize * sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (::ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str, pBuff, dwSize))
        str = pBuff;

    free(pBuff);
}
```

Comment: "*is it possible to make this without calling twice the ExpandEnvironmentStrings?*" - the only way to do that is to provide `ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` with a very large buffer up front, and even then you are not guaranteed to be large enough. There is nothing wrong with calling `ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` twice (a lot of Win32 APIs are designed to work that way). The real problem is the `malloc()`, that really should not be used in C++, so you should thrive to replace that instead, such as with `std::vector` or `std::(w)string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks! but at least to get rid of the malloc

Comment: If you use Microsoft `CString`, then there is already [CString::GetBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-160#getbuffer) for that purpose. By the way, you should declare variables just before there first use and also stop other C habits like malloc/free.

Comment: @Phil1970 you are right :) I forgot that